# Stop running script but not programm it started

Tags: linux, bash, chromium

I have a script on my Raspberry Pi that starts the browser in kiosk mode. But if I do so the script keeps running even if i pipe the output to /dev/null like this `./script 2> /dev/null`

If i stop the script with ctrl+c the browser gets killed as well. How can I run the script without having it to run in my terminal forever?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add `&` at the end of the line.

also in the terminal you can do the same. but if you close it the process you started is killed even if you add & ,so you have to disown the process by adding `& disown` ,which you don't need in the script.

Answer (score 0):

adding & at the end of the line puts the process in the background, that is correct. But if you exit the session, the process is killed.

There is another solution:

`nohup script.sh &` also makes sure the process keeps running even if you exit the terminal.